# ¿Por qué el dropdown de bootstrap no se expande?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un navbar donde esta el menú, pero el último dropdown no se expande y no sé por qué. Ya intenté actualizar los archivos de bootstrap con la última version pero aún así no funciona.

No sé si alguno sabe cómo podría solucionarlo o bien qué podría impementar.

Les agrego una imagen donde se ve un ejemplo de cómo se ve el menu.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el HTML5.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky">
        <div class="container">
        <a href="inicio.php" class="navbar-brand">CI-<span class="text-primary">TECHNOLOGY</span></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto pt-3 pt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="inicio.php" class="nav-link">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="nosotros.php" class="nav-link">Sobre nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="servicios.php" class="nav-link">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="galeria.php" class="nav-link">Galeria</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="contacto.php" class="nav-link">Contacto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="comentarios.php" class="nav-link">Más</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Clientes
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="InicioSesion.php" class="nav-link">¡Iniciar Sesión!</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div> <!-- .container -->
</nav> <!-- .navbar -->
```

Estoy incluyendo el css de bootstrap y el js pero aún así no abre.

Comment: Buen día, `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarContent"` están escritos mal en tu código, les hace falta el `bs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa en que versión estas de bootstrap. Si usas la 4.x o inferior cambiar los data-bs- por data-, y si estás en la 5.x entonces al contrario, cambia todos los data- por data-bs- como ya te han dicho. Por el problema que describes en tu pregunta me imagino que estas en una 4.x.